# Increasing functions and the Definite Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $a(x)$ be a polynomial that increases as $x$ increases. Show that the polynomial $\displaystyle b(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}a(t)dt$ $(x>0)$ also increases with $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition reads
\begin{align}
xb(x) & = \int_0^x a(t) dt \\
\end{align}
Differentiate on both sides with respect to $x$, 
\begin{align}
b(x) + xb'(x) & = a(x) \\
\end{align}
Therefore, for $x > 0$,
\begin{align}
b'(x) & = \frac{a(x) - b(x)}{x} \geq 0
\end{align}
where the inequality holds since $a(t)$ is increasing, thus
$$b(x) = \frac{\int_0^x a(t) dt}{x} \leq \frac{a(x)(x - 0)}{x} = a(x).$$

Therefore $b$ is also increasing on $(0, +\infty)$.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the fact that positive derivative implies that the function is increasing.